# Google Maps V3.31 DOM Markers vs Tile Markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

V 3.31 of the API includes this change:

> Make the first 256 Markers DOM Markers by default, then make
>   subsequent markers Tile Markers. Current default is all Tile Markers

I believe this may be causing me a problem when using MarkerClusterer along with Marker Labels. The map is failing with this error when larger numbers of markers are used.

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.labelDiv_.parentNode.removeChild')
```

Disabling clustering removes the error so I'm wondering if there is some conflict between these two different types of markers and clustering?

For now I've reverted to the prior release, but that's just a temporary fix.
Is it possible to change this default so that it reverts to using all Tile Markers? Perhaps specify the Marker type when defining it?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else has the same problem. [Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/issues/393) is a discussion of the problem and a workaround for markerwithlabel.js